# Oracle PL/SQL dealing with values not found in the cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to find a value in a cursor and do something to it, also if a value is not found, I need to perform a different action. I am using FOR LOOP cursor:

```
CURSOR cursor1 IS
   SELECT....;

FOR c1 in cursor1 LOOP
    IF c1.myvalue = l_val THEN
        --the value found
        --perform an action
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

The above works fine for when I do something with the values that are found in the cursor, but how do I capture the ones that were not found?

Comment: Use `ELSE` portion in `IF` for values that not found

Comment: I hate it when you find snot in the cursor :-)

Comment: Haha, Nice @TonyAndrews . Let me edit it.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture  the ones that were not found"?  Always give examples to make it clear rather than we assuming what you actually want.

Comment: @Tejash, that will only tell me if the value is not found in the current row, not the entire cursor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean, what should you do if the cursor does not return a match for `l_val`?

Using your method you could do this:

```
l_found BOOLEAN := FALSE;
CURSOR cursor1 IS
   SELECT....;

FOR c1 in cursor1 LOOP
    IF c1.myvalue = l_val THEN
        --the value found
        --perform an action
        l_found := TRUE;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

IF NOT l_found THEN
    -- Do something when not found
END IF;
```

But really you do not want to be fetching all the rows in a SELECT statement and then checking each one for a match.  Instead you could do the matching in the SELECT:

```
l_found BOOLEAN := FALSE;
CURSOR cursor1 IS
   SELECT....
   WHERE myvalue = l_val;

FOR c1 in cursor1 LOOP
   --the value found
   --perform an action
   l_found := TRUE;
END LOOP;

IF NOT l_found THEN
    -- Do something when not found
END IF;
```

Comment: I like the second solution better. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that there boolean datatype available in oracle database? I am sure that oracle do not support boolean datatype.

Comment: @Tejash PL/SQL has datatypes that can be used in code that are not available in tables or views. And PL/SQL has had a boolean for quite awhile. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i10924